# Serialize nested objects in C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I got 2 user-defined classes, called *Event* and *Image*, *Event* has a property stored a list of *EventImage*, called *EventImages*. And in *Image* class, there's a *byte[]* type property which store the byte[] of one Image file.

Here's the definitions of the 2 classes :

```
[Serializable]
public Class Event
{
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime EventTime { get; set;}
    public List<Image> EventImages { get; set; }
    ...
}

[Serializable]
public Class Image
{
    public DateTime ImageTime { get; set;}
    public byte[] pData {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Now my question is, I want to serialize my *Event* object to *byte[]*, and I expect that the whole content of it will be *serialize*, too, but it seems that I failed.

Here's my code to do *Serialization* :

```
    public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryFormatter bF = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream mS = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bF.Serialize(mS, obj);
                return mS.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

and here's the code for verification :

```
Console.WriteLine(ObjectToByteArray(Event));
Console.WriteLine(ObjectToByteArray(Event.EventImage));        
Console.WriteLine(ObjectToByteArray(Event.EventImages.FirstOrDefault().pData));
```

and the results are(just assumption value) :
100 200 300

But I expect the result should be 600(100+200+300), 500(200+300) and 300.

So, I think my *serialization* doesn't really *serialize* the whole content, it just serialize properties with Basic Types, but without the nested objects, am I right?

I've searched lots of posts, and I found plenty of answers to similar questions mentioned "XML Serialization", but I'm not sure whether its helpful or not. Need I use that or is there any other better way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question, are you intending to deserialize the object at some point or is this for some different purpose? Have you tried deserializing the object and checking the contents against the first object?
Side note - (opinion) it seems that the community is generally moving away from binary serialization unless there is a specific reason to use it. If you use a JSON serializer these issues are far easier to debug since you can see the data right in the JSON output. Try using JSON.NET http://www.newtonsoft.com/json to serialize it and look at the resulting file.

Comment: @drobertson Thanks for your advice! I've used JSON format before, and I think that's a charm to serialize and transfer data, too. But the reason that I need to do this is that I need to use some specific library, and it receive only _byte array_ format. I haven't tried to _deserialize_ the result yet, I will try it later, hope that can help. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your code, it is pretty textbook. I don't see any areas where the binary serialization would obviously fail. Interpreting the byte array output is another thing entirely. That just makes my head hurt. Remember that the binary serializer does more than just store your data in a big chunk, it also has metadata properties inside it to describe how to reconstitute the data. You are looking inside the sausage factory with that.

Comment: One thing stuck in my head from your comment above. You are using a library that expects a byte array format. Does this format have a spec or is  it specifically asking for a byte array from a binary serialized object. That is a fairly odd thing to be looking for unless it is a homegrown solution. That said, I have used them for data purposes, but the byte array data was alway built around a data specification. A binary serialized output wouldn't have fit the spec.

Comment: @drobertson Well, I'm not quiet sure what does the _textbook_ meaning... is my code too simple? Actually, I can't see any part that may cause error in my code, either. Thanks for your mention! I think there's much I need to know about _byte[]_, as you said, **Interpreting the byte array output is another thing entirely**, maybe I should search regarding another ways, thanks!

Comment: @drobertson The .dll file was developed from another team, which was written in C++, and one of the parameters the API will take is _unsigned char *_ type. That's why I convert my object to _byte array_ in my C# code.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstand. All that means is that it looks clean and basic like you would find in a textbook. A good example.
I would start looking at what the library you need to use expects to be getting for data. Look at the data specification if it has one. This is like saying a library wants a string input. What is supposed to be in the string? How will the library interpret the data. Does it expect you to have data elements in certain places. Are there rules for delimiters. 
I could be wrong, but a binary serialized object as a Byte Array seems like a very unlikely way to pass data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105858/discussion-between-drobertson-and-alanight).

Answer (score 1):

Quickly made a test to check equality.  It passes.

Serializes and deserializes correctly.

Conclusion, don't judge whether something is happening or not until you've tested it.

```
    public static void Run()
    {
        var i = new Image
        {
            ImageTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
            pData = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()
        };

        var e = new Event
        {
            Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            EventTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
            EventImages = new List<Image> {i}
        };

        var bytes = ObjectToByteArray(e);
        var e2 = ObjectFromByteArray(bytes);

        Console.WriteLine(e.Equals(e2));
    }

    public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var bF = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var mS = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bF.Serialize(mS, obj);
            return mS.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static object ObjectFromByteArray(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var bF = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var mS = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            return bF.Deserialize(mS);
        }
    }
```